Using rsync, how to exclude a specific hidden directory and all subdirs from transfer
I'm trying to rsync some data and exclude a directory called ".snapshots".
So the path to the source is something like:
/a/b/theDirectory/

and it has within it:
/a/b/theDirectory/.snapshots/

I want to rsync this, but options such as
rsync -avvA --exclude /a/b/theDirectory/.snapshots /a/b/theDirectory/ <destination> 

don't work and still include the .snapshots dir.
I've tried double and single quotes; escaping the \., putting a / at the end; putting * or /* at the end but all fail.
The only thing I've been able to make work is to use --exclude '.snapshots'
but this runs the risk of something I didn't intend to get excluded (in case there is a ".snapshots" at some other level of the dir hierarchy).
Could any one advise please?
Many thanks

You simply need to anchor the exclude filter pattern with a leading "/":
--exclude /.snapshots

See the man page discussion:

PATTERN MATCHING RULES
A pattern that starts with a / is anchored to the start of the transfer path



Thanks for this!
